# exclude file name from powershell selection in batch

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I have selected file with powershell (GUI) like this

```
for %%I in (powershell.exe) do if "%%~$PATH:I" neq "" (
    set chooser_file=powershell "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.windows.forms|Out-Null;$f=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog;$f.InitialDirectory='';$f.Filter='Positive Registry Files (*.reg)||All Files (*.*)|*.*';$f.showHelp=$true;$f.ShowDialog()|Out-Null;$f.FileName"
)

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%chooser_file%') do set "regfile=%%I"
```

now,
the set is giving me the full file path with the file name:

```
C:\Deploy\REG_DEPLOY\POS_regs\Safe_Year\Safe_Year.reg
```

I want to exclude only the file name and extestion.

thank you

Comment: You want to exclude(remove) the filename and extension = Get folder location. Or do you want to EXTRACT the filename and extension = Get the file + ext.?   What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your pick:

Line one returns `filename.ext`
Line two returns `drive:\path\`

```
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%chooser_file%') do set "regfile=%%~nxI"
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%chooser_file%') do set "regfile=%%~dpI"
```